# Android sleep for short interval

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, timer, sleep

I'm trying to cap FPS in my OpenGL thread. To do this, I'm adding a sleep in `onDrawFrame()`.
Unfortunately, it seems that sleeping less that 12 ms doesn't sleep at all - FPS remain the same. Only if I use values higher than 12 ms it actually sleeps and reduces FPS. Is there some technical limitation of Dalvik which prevents very short sleeps?

I've tried both `Thread.sleep()` and `SystemClock.sleep()` with the same results.

Comment: The FPS not changing does not necessarily mean that the sleep is not working. If your rendering is GPU limited, adding a short sleep on the CPU will not slow it down. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Android normally caps rendering at 60 fps. Are you trying to go down to something like 30 fps? To save power?

Comment: Yes I try to reduce rendering speed to exactly 30 fps by spending exactly 33 ms in `onDrawFrame()`.

Comment: Ideally you would use `eglSwapInterval()` for this purpose, but some searching suggests that it may not be supported on Android, or at least not on all devices. There's a relatively recent discussion about the topic here, if you haven't seen it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43118. Sorry, I don't have a solution. I have a feeling that everything based on timers in the application is not going to work consistently.

Comment: Yep I've researched `eglSwapInterval()` but because of surfaceflinger it makes no sense - architecture of Android doesn't allow direct rendering and control over vsync - it just always swaps buffers at max 60 fps.